How to make form full width in filament custom pages
I am trying to create a multistep business registration page but the form with is so small that steps cannot be visible without horizontal scrolling.
I would like for my form to cover the entire page width but it remains a cut-out
as below:

Here is the code:

<?php

namespace App\Filament\Pages\Tenancy;

//...

class RegisterTeam extends RegisterTenant
{
    public static function getLabel(): string
    {
        return 'Register Team';
    }

    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Wizard::make([
                    Step::make('Name')
                        ->description('Give the category a clear and unique name')
                        ->schema([
                            TextInput::make('name')
                                ->required()
                                ->live()
                                ->afterStateUpdated(fn($state, callable $set) => $set('slug', Str::slug($state))),
                            TextInput::make('slug')
                                ->disabled()
                                ->required(),
                        ]),
                    Step::make('Description')
                        ->description('Add some extra details')
                        ->schema([
                            MarkdownEditor::make('description')
                                ->columnSpan('full'),
                        ]),
                    Step::make('Visibility')
                        ->description('Control who can view it')
                        ->schema([
                            Toggle::make('is_visible')
                                ->label('Visible to customers.')
                                ->default(true),
                        ]),
                ])
            ]);
    }

    protected function handleRegistration(array $data): Team
    {
        $team = Team::create($data);

        $team->members()->attach(auth()->user());

        return $team;
    }
}



I have tried adding ->columns(12) on the $form but it's still not widening. someone help, please.
Here is the code for register view and form view
register-tenant.blade.php
<x-filament-panels::page.simple>
    <x-filament-panels::form id="form" wire:submit="register">
        {{ $this->form }}

        <x-filament-panels::form.actions
            :actions="$this->getCachedFormActions()"
            :full-width="$this->hasFullWidthFormActions()"
        />
    </x-filament-panels::form>
</x-filament-panels::page.simple>

x-filament-panels::form
@props([
    'method' => 'post',
])

<form
    method="{{ $method }}"
    x-data="{ isProcessing: false }"
    x-on:submit="if (isProcessing) $event.preventDefault()"
    x-on:form-processing-started="isProcessing = true"
    x-on:form-processing-finished="isProcessing = false"
    {{ $attributes->class(['fi-form grid gap-y-6']) }}
>
    {{ $slot }}
</form>

I think the problem is there on that gap-y-6, how can I remove it?

use a custom blade instead of the tenant registration one.

Could you provide us the blade file that calling this page?

@N69S there is no way to customize this form?

@Joseph I have edited post with the extra code.

Try this it works for pages as shown here in the Docs, but should work forms too. If not i would try to create a custom layout
use Filament\Support\Enums\MaxWidth;

public function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        // ...
        ->maxContentWidth(MaxWidth::Full);
 }


Here is the form page
@props([
    'method' => 'post',
])

<form
    method="{{ $method }}"
    x-data="{ isProcessing: false }"
    x-on:submit="if (isProcessing) $event.preventDefault()"
    x-on:form-processing-started="isProcessing = true"
    x-on:form-processing-finished="isProcessing = false"
    {{ $attributes->class(['fi-form grid gap-y-6']) }}
>
    {{ $slot }}
</form>


